# Entity Framework lambda query to Get info from other tables

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm getting data from a table using entity framework lambda query:

```
db.Orders.Where(x => x.OrderID == orderid)
         .Select(x => new JOrders 
         { 
             id = x.OrderID, 
             customer_id = x.CustomerID, 
             product_id = x.ProductID,  
             account_id = x.AccountID
         }).toList()
```

`CustomerID`, `ProductID` and `AccountID` are **primary keys** from separate tables i.e. `Customers, Products, Accounts` respectively. I would like to get Name column for these IDs from their respective tables and return that instead. I'm looking for an optimized lambda query since the number of records returned could be in thousands.

Comment: Do you want an SQL query?

Comment: lambda query. Would sql be more performant?

Comment: Are the navigation properties set up correctly? Then you could just do just `CustomerName = x.Customer.Name`. If not, you'd have to join them manually.

Comment: Yes, these are setup but my understanding is that it will result in separate query, rather than a traditional left outer join - which is preferred in SQL world?

Comment: You can make use of Parallel Linq (PLinQ) =>  https://www.infoworld.com/article/3021870/how-to-work-with-parallel-linq-in-c.html if you want to fetch from multiple tables at the same time

Comment: And please post your actual code. Your current exmaple was missing a closing bracket and `.toList()` is missing its capital T. Furthermore, `customer_id` is not `CustomerID`, like you've written in your question.

Comment: Well' use the navigation properties then. If in doubt you can always check the generated SQL, to see if it is performant enough.

Comment: if you have your navigation properties properly setup, you can just do `x.Order.Name`,`x.Customer.Name`  and same for the rest of the properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't make an relating in EF you can manual Join like this

```
db.Orders.Where(x => x.OrderID == orderid)
.Join(db.Customers,Order => Order.OrderID, Customer => Customer.CustomerID, (Order, Customer) => new {OrderID = Order.id, CutomerName = Customer.Name, more fields..}).ToList()
```

But if you did have an relate table you can just call it

```
db.Orders.Where(x => x.OrderID == orderid)
         .Select(x => new JOrders 
         { 
             id = x.OrderID, 
             customer_id = x.CustomerID, 
             product_id = x.ProductID,  
             account_id = x.AccountID,
             name = x.Customers.Name
         }).toList()
```

Comment: For the first one, how do I join other tables i.e. Products and Accounts?
In the second case, do you know if it results in a single SQL query?

Comment: For first repeat .Join and join another table but you can use only selected fields from previous Join, For second Yes ef will translate it to single SQL

Answer (score 1):

If you have set the navigation properties correctly in your `Orders` class. It's just a matter of including them in your query and then you can use those properties in your lambda. Something like this:

```
db.Orders
.Include(x => x.Customer)
.Include(x => x.Product)
.Include(x => x.Account)
.Where(x => x.OrderID == orderid)
         .Select(x => new JOrders 
         { 
             id = x.OrderID, 
             customer_name = x.Customer.Name, 
             product_name = x.Product.Name,  
             account_name = x.Account.Name
         }).toList()
```

But I believe you will have multiple `Products` in an `Order`, so you might have to change it accordingly.

Comment: Didn't realise @Aarif had commented this same thing.